# Using colors in WebGL

Tags: javascript, html, colors, webgl

I have a program that divides a triangle. I'm trying to change the color of the triangle by pressing the r,g,b key respectively. Also I have button that i would like to clear the screen if you could point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it.

CODE:

```
var canvas;
var gl;

var points = [];

var numTimesToSubdivide = 0;

var colors = [
vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // red
vec4( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // green
vec4( 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0 ),  // blue
];


function init()
{
canvas = document.getElementById( "gl-canvas" );

gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL( canvas );
if ( !gl ) { alert( "WebGL isn't available" ); }

//
//  Initialize our data for the Sierpinski Gasket
//

// First, initialize the corners of our gasket with three points.

var vertices = [
    vec2( -1, -1 ),
    vec2(  0,  1 ),
    vec2(  1, -1 )
];
divideTriangle( vertices[0], vertices[1], vertices[2],
                numTimesToSubdivide);

//
//  Configure WebGL
//
gl.viewport( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
gl.clearColor( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );

//  Load shaders and initialize attribute buffers

var program = initShaders( gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader" );
gl.useProgram( program );

// Load the data into the GPU


/* 
var bufferId = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferId );
gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 50000, gl.STATIC_DRAW );
gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, flatten(points)); 
*/


var cBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cBuffer );
gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(colors), gl.STATIC_DRAW );

var vColor = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vColor" );
gl.vertexAttribPointer( vColor, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vColor );

var vBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer );
gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(points), gl.STATIC_DRAW );

// Associate out shader variables with our data buffer

var vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vPosition" );
gl.vertexAttribPointer( vPosition, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vPosition );




    document.getElementById("slider").onchange = function() {
    numTimesToSubdivide = event.srcElement.value;
};


render();
};

window.onkeydown = function( event ) {
    var key = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
    switch( key ) {
      case 'R':

        break;

      case 'G':

        break;

      case 'B':

        break;
    }
};


function triangle( a, b, c )
{
points.push( a, b, c );

}

function divideTriangle( a, b, c, count )
{

// check for end of recursion

if ( count === 0 ) {
    triangle( a, b, c );
    triangle( a, b, c );
}
else {

    //bisect the sides

    var ab = mix( a, b, 0.5 );
    var ac = mix( a, c, 0.5 );
    var bc = mix( b, c, 0.5 );


    --count;

    // three new triangles

    divideTriangle( a, ab, ac, count );
    divideTriangle( c, ac, bc, count );
    divideTriangle( b, bc, ab, count );
}
}

window.onload = init;

 function render()
{
gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
gl.drawArrays( gl.LINES, 0, points.length );
points = [];
requestAnimFrame(init);
}
```

Comment: [Learning WebGL](http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?page_id=1217)

Comment: [WebGLfundamenals.org](http://webglfundamentals.org)

Comment: ps: "LearningWebGL.com" teaches many bad and confusing practices.